# Python write special string to CSV

Tags: python, csv, special-characters

I have a problems when writing special string to CSV.

Problem Solved:

```
def csv_write(s):
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
    writer.writerow(s)
f.close()

def csv_read(path):
with open('test.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

csv_write(['Ngày tháng năm',''])

csv_read('test.csv')
```

Thank for all.

Comment: if you are opening your csv in Excel, this may be a excel encoder problem, https://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad: csv output: b'Ng\xc3\xa0y th\xc3\xa1ng n\xc4\x83m'. Tks

Comment: @Shijith: file was closed every test. tks

Comment: This error shows up in python2. Use python 3 and file will get written properly. Your code works perfectly in python3.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas: my python version: 3.8.0 64-bit. Tks

Comment: Yes this code is working in python 2.6, 3.7 and 3.8 also please check again....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default encoding scheme of python is `UTF-8`.
The text mentioned here is in `UTF-8` encoding.
If you try to open the file in application which reads encoding as `ASCII` character, you will be displayed - `NgÃ y thÃ¡ng nÄm`

Hover to the site and enter your UTF-8 string, you can see the `ASCII` will print the same.
https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-utf8-to-ascii

The program generates the correct output.

```
import csv


def test(s):
    with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(s)


test(['Ngày tháng năm', ''])
```

Above code outputs the same text in the program.
Maybe you can try changing the Application through which you are reading the file.

`Output`

```
Ngày tháng năm,
```

Comment: tks. I found where i 'm wrong

Comment: Those characters are undefined in ASCII. You are using a legacy 8-bit encoding like Latin-1 or Windows-1252.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working correctly. You are using a tool which displays the CSV in Latin-1 instead of UTF-8 and that's why it looks wrong.

Comment: I using Excel 2019. How can i change the excel encode?

Comment: I don't use Excel, but try using the `utf-8-sig` encoding like it says in the duplicate question. This will add a UTF-8 BOM character to the beginning of the file, which should somewhat help Excel's feeble little mind (though you're still probably better off using something less dumb).

Comment: tks. It's working!!!